# I need to disable Home Key or perform some activity when home key is pressed in android

Tags: android

I need perform some action on press of home key like starting activity when some one presses the home key...how to do it?

Comment: See SO answers <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button">here</a>, <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278535/disable-home-button-in-android-toddler-app">here</a> and <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-home-key">here</a>.

Comment: Actually i need to perform some actions on the press of home button... Like i need to call a Log out API for my Application... As users will be online in my application and i want users to logout on press of home key when application goes at backgroud... CAn u help me out on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Is It possible to disable the click of home button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button)

Comment: I need to perform some action on press of home key...thts it....

Comment: Then write your own home screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you really want is to perform some actions when your activity leaves the foreground, see the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). Your activity will have its `onPause` method called when it is no longer in the foreground, and `onStop` called when it is no longer visible.