# Android: Never show Support Action Bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-immersive

There is a way to completly hide the support action bar, even if the user scroll down from top to bottom? **Never show it**.

[image]

This solution works but only temporary

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

I've tried also:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

and

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

or similar.

**When the user scroll down, the bar re-appear.**

I need it because i'm making my personal launcher and I've got my personal support action bar

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32377169/6950238) question and answers.

Answer (score 1):

> When the user scroll down, the bar re-appear.

It seems to me it's not available to completely disable/hide status bar.

From [`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY):

> When system bars are hidden in immersive mode, they can be revealed temporarily with system gestures, such as swiping from the top of the screen. These transient system bars will overlay app’s content, may have some degree of transparency, and will automatically hide after a short timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```